# Why is my media query rule not being prioritized?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm using media queries to make my site resposnive. In my CSS doc, the media queries are below all other styles. I'm am using diplay: none; which works perfectly but on another div the original width is taking priority even when I reduce the browser size.

Image of dev console:

[image: Image of dev console]

Do I really have to add `!important` to every media rule?

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 930px) {

    /* INDEX */
nav ul {
    display: none;
}

#sliderContainer {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
}


}
```

Comment: Have you used your browser console to check which style is actually being applied?

Comment: Are you able to rearrange the order in which the stylesheets are loaded?  To clarify, media queries don't add specificity.  That means that in order for a media query to take effect, it usually has to be included after the rule it overrides.  It looks like the two rules are in separate stylesheets.  You would need to rearrange them to change the cascading order.

Comment: Or increase your specificity for the selector ....

Comment: Is possible if index.css is load before you have !important there  ?

Comment: Adding to what Joseph and Dani said if your selector is overqualified your media query won't take precedence over it.

Comment: The sheet with the queries in is higher in the header than my index.css

Comment: The last will take precedence ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule at line `#112` in `index.css` is also applied by `#sliderContainer` and not by `nav li`, as you state in your question (it can be seen in the image you posted). Because it is met later and has same specificity, it **applies**.

If you place `!important` on a rule, you'll probably need to use `!important` when trying to override it, and before you know it, half your rules will be `!important` and fixing responsiveness is going to be a nightmare. Either slightly increase specificity of your rule or change their order.

**Very important note:** `@media` queries do not add any specificity to `CSS` rules. They just make them apply (when conditions are true) or not (when not true).

**Useful note:** A very good technique to always keep specificity of your selectors as low as possible is to ***place your custom stylesheets last inside `<head>`***, after any theme/libraries/plugins stylesheets. Whenever you need to override anything, you just copy-paste the selector from where it is currently defined, and only placing it in your custom stylesheet will make it have priority without higher specificity.

Comment: Is it met later becuase it's further down in the sheet? becuase styles.css is higher in the header than index.css What would you recommend is the best practice to arrange them etc?

Comment: It's met later because `styles.css` is read first (higher in header, as you said) and `index.css` is read later (lower in header). Change their order in header and the rule in `styles.css` will apply. I'll add another note to the answer (how to not increase specificity of your code. Good clarification question!

Answer (score 0):

Adding !important tags to your media queries may be necessary, should you need to override styles provided by a pre-set template or development platform. For example I work with Squarespace, and have to override their default styles from time to time in this way - however, as with myself, I can understand your aversion towards doing so.

I know I'm not supposed to "ask for clarification" here, but my lack of rep prevents me from simply making a comment: are you working on a web develop platform similar to Squarespace, Weebly, etc., and does applying the !important tag in fact achieve the desired result?

Best,

Tyler